# Nginx Rewrite Location to subfolders

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I need help to determine what's the best way to split characters to sub-folders? What I specifically need is to Rewrite url `/file/12345.jpg` to `/1/2/3/4/5/12345.jpg` FS path. (numbers are not restricted to only these - they could be in any combination of digits, for example: /file/123.jpg, /file/123456789.jpg and etc.)

This is base location.

```
location ~ ^/file/(.+)\.(.+)$ {
   ....
}
```

One possibility is to describe all variations:

```
location ~ ^/file/(\d)\.(.+)$ {
   alias /file/$1/$1.$2;
}
```

```
location ~ ^/file/(\d)(\d)\.(.+)$ {
   alias /file/$1/$2/$1$2.$3;
}
```

and etc

but it's ugly and not productive.

Comment: I think that any solution will involve a regular expression with several captures and using `alias`, `root` or `try_files` to locate the file within the filesystem.

Comment: @RichardSmith Yeah I know it can happen with several locations/rewrites. This is what I'm trying to avoid. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/file/12af5.jpg` to `/1/2/a/f/5/12af5.jpg`:

```
location ~ ^/files/((\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w))\.(.*) {
  rewrite "/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1.$7" break;
}
```

For more dynamic functionality, consider using [rewrite_by_lua](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#rewrite_by_lua) (custom nginx build required) or use [OpenResty](https://openresty.org/), 
 which includes it out of the box.  You could also proxy requests to a Python/Node/Php/etc backend server to dynamically redirect with your language of choice.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't thought that it's gonna work like that (because it will generate a lot of ////). 
This is the Location that I used.
`
    location ~ ^/file/(\d?)(\d?)(\d?)(\d?)(\d?)(\d?)(\d?)(\d?)(\d?)\.(.+) {
      alias "/var/www/files/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$9/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.$10";
    }
`

Isn't there any other variant that will for example insert `/` in between every character?