# nginx rewrite rules subfolder to file

Tags: nginx

I have dynamic files on the server:

- allen.php
- bob.php
- candy321.php
- david.php

and I would like to add rewrite rules in Nginx, expected the URLs are:

- http://example.com/allen
- https://example.com/bob/?param=value
- http://example.com/candy321/
- https://example.com/david.php?param=value

I found a similar one, but I have no idea how to modify it to fit my case:
[Nginx Rewrite Location to subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61777025/nginx-rewrite-location-to-subfolders)

Comment: The solution will depend on what should have a priority, `/webroot/candy321/index.php` or `/webroot/candy321.php`, assuming both exists.

Comment: Additionally, what do you want to do with the requests which don't match an existing PHP file? Should such requests return `404 Not Found` error?

Comment: @IvanShatsky if requesting the filename which is not exists, using the default 404 handling. And I would like to achieve by RewriteRules, thank you.

Comment: I'm not going to solve this using rewrite rules, I'm going to solve this using `try_files` directive. What about the first question? Or there won't be any `index.php` files? And one more question, can you add your current PHP handler location to your question?

Comment: Server contains a dynamic files in root folder, but I would like to access the file using upper URL, means the server does not exists any folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a modified version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21911610/7121513) answer:

```
root /path/to/your/webroot;
index index.php index.html;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
}

location @extensionless-php {
    rewrite ^(.*)/$ $1.php last;
    rewrite ^ $uri.php last;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$uri;
    fastcgi_pass ... # path to your PHP-FPM socket file or listening IP address/port
}
```